# Jquery: ShowBubblePopup not working

Tags: jquery, bubble-popup

I'm using this Jquery plugin: http://www.vegabit.com/jquery_bubble_popup_v2/

Works perfectly.

Now, I want to use the ShowBubblePopup event on some other area of my page (which doesn't trigger the bubble directly) like a sidebar text link or something.

It's not working

```
$('#SideBarText').mouseover(function(){
    $('#TheBigPopup').ShowBubblePopup();
});
```

Should I just be putting the above code into my "head" between the Jquery script tags?

Here is what the relevant area of my head code block looks like right now:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/jquery.bubblepopup.v2.3.1.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.bubblepopup.v2.3.1.min.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.wolf').CreateBubblePopup({
            position : 'left',
            openingSpeed: 1,
            closingSpeed: 1,
            align    : 'center',
            width   :'260px',
            selectable: true,
            innerHtml: '<h3>Wolf Company bubble thing',
            innerHtmlStyle: {
                color:'black', 
                'text-align':'left'
                },
            themeName:  'grey',
            themePath:  '/images/jquerybubble'
        });
    });
    //-->
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing `</h3>` closing tag in the `innerHtml` which won't be helping matters.